# How to perform 2x $stmt->execute(); ? I'm getting an error

Tags: php

I'm getting an error (so obvious error)

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object...

I want to check if user has provided his information when verifying his information. If no, it's a successful echo, but if yes, then I get that error... My php code :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['configured'])){

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT gender FROM members WHERE username =  ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->bind_result($gender);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        if(empty($gender)){
            echo "<font color='#DB4D4D'>Verification failed! Please provide your information and try again...</font>";
        } else {
             $_POST['configured'] = 1;
             $sql = "
             UPDATE members
             SET configured = ?
             WHERE username = ?
            ";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['configured'], $_SESSION['username']); // This is the error line
            $ok = $stmt->execute();

            if ($ok == TRUE) {
                echo "<p><font color='#00CC00'>Your information has been verified.</font><p>
                      <form action='index.php'> <input type='submit' class='buttondiv' value='Continue to Home Page'>";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " .$stmt->error;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Where is problem?

BTW: The error line is not incorrect itself.. there has to be something else going on...

Comment: Please fix your code indentation, that will make problems easier to track down.

Comment: What is wrong with the indentation? You mean that 3 brackets at the end?

Comment: Starting with the first line the indentation is bad and makes the code hard to follow. FIFY.

Comment: Thanks.. But I don't need it though :D

Comment: You must work in a silo and never expect others to look at, maintain or troubleshoot your code.  :D

Comment: Well yeah u're right :D

Comment: Do a `var_dump($stmt)` before the `bind_param()`. What do you get?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - bool(false)

Comment: There is your issue - it should return an object. If it returned false an error occurred. Time to sprinkle in some [MySQLi Error Checking](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: can you just tell me where to add it? xD I never know how to come back from that php.net with something I can apply :D

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Could you help me with that error checking ? :|

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `session_start()` to the top of the page. Your bind fails because there is no `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: This is not the full code.. this is just a part of the code...my full code has 300+ lines...

Comment: So you think the error exists in the lines you posted? Does the 300+ lines start with `session_start()`?

Comment: I know that it's right there, because I had just a code for the "Confirm my information" without that checking for gender and it was working... After I added that checking for gender, it pops the error

Answer (score 0):

mysqli->prepare() returned FALSE therefore $stmt->bind_param() was effectively something like FALSE->bind_param(), FALSE is not an object but a Boolean (not an object in PHP) hence the error message `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

mysqli->prepare() failing is always an option for various reasons.
Therefore *always* check the return value.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(...);
if ( !$stmt ) {
  trigger_error( __LINE__ . ': '.print_r($mysqli->error_list, true), E_USER_ERROR );
}
```

Same with most of the other mysqli functions/methods, bind_param(), execute() ... always check the return value. If it's FALSE or NULL, something went wrong.
In short: add error handling!

---

Let's condense your script a little bit:

```
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()){
   ...
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['configured'], $_SESSION['username']);
    $ok = $stmt->execute();
```

You have an (active) statement in $stmt which you try to "overwrite" within the loop.
a) what would the next iteration of `while ($stmt->fetch())` do?
b) that doesn't work with mysql; only one active statement per connection.

Answer (score -1):

According to me you should replace:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['configured'], $_SESSION['username']);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['configured']);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: I don't think that this can work.. bind_param can not be in separated lines and not in 2 codes... Trust me.. I tried it once, and it didn't work :D it has to be in one code

Comment: Why @DDA? PHP allows multiple elements in [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: You are right @Jay Blanchard, i just discover it was possible.

Comment: But i didn't find this possibility with pdo in the php manual, is it only for mysqli ?